# ListView not refreshed until user interaction

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged, holoeverywhere

I have a ListView and a custom adapter. When the user changes the sort type from a spinner, I want to redraw the list with the new items. The problem is that the ListView is re-drawn only after I interact with it on the device (start scrolling for example).

```
if (update) {
                mOfferList = (ArrayList<PositionSearchItem>) psr
                            .getPositionSearchItem();

                mAdapter.clear();
                mAdapter.addAll(mOfferList);
                mAdapter.notifydataSetChanged()
                mList.invalidate();
                mList.invalidateViews();

}
```

I have also tried to fully reset a new instance of my adapter to the list, it is giving the same result except that the list becomes blank at first and appears on user interaction.

**I'm using HoloEveryWhere maybe this is an important info.**

EDIT : Here is some more code

```
@EFragment(R.layout.list_fragment_results)
public class ResultsListFragment extends Fragment {

    @ViewById(R.id.search_results_list)
    ListView mList;
    @ViewById(R.id.search_result_list_spinner)
    Spinner mSpinner;
    MainActivity mActivity;
    private String mTypedText;
    private List<String> mSortType;
    private ResultsListFragment mFrag;
    private Bundle mOffersPageBundle;
    private SearchResultsListAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<PositionSearchItem> mOfferList;

    @AfterViews
    public void afterViews() {
        mFrag = this;
        mActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        mSortType = new ArrayList<String>();
        mSortType.add(SearchResultSortType.SCORE_DESCENDING);
        mOfferList = new ArrayList<PositionSearchItem>();

        mOffersPageBundle = getArguments();
        PositionSearchResponse psr = mOffersPageBundle.getParcelable("offers");
        mTypedText = mOffersPageBundle.getString("typedText");

        mOfferList = (ArrayList<PositionSearchItem>) psr.getPositionSearchItem();

        mAdapter = new SearchResultsListAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mOfferList, mTypedText,
                mSortType, mActivity.getLat(), mActivity.getLon());
        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        this.setListeners();
    }

    private void setListeners() {

        mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new org.holoeverywhere.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(
                    org.holoeverywhere.widget.AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {
                Boolean update = false;
                PositionSearchResponse psr = null;
                switch (pos) {
                case 0:
                    if (mSortType.get(0) != SearchResultSortType.SCORE_DESCENDING) {
                        mSortType.clear();
                        mSortType.add(SearchResultSortType.SCORE_DESCENDING);
                        psr = processSearch(mTypedText, mSortType, 0, mActivity);
                        update = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (mSortType.get(0) != SearchResultSortType.DATE) {
                        mSortType.clear();
                        mSortType.add(SearchResultSortType.DATE);
                        psr = processSearch(mTypedText, mSortType, 0, mActivity);
                        update = true;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }

                if (update) {
                    mOffersPageBundle.putParcelable("offers", psr);
                    mOfferList = (ArrayList<PositionSearchItem>) psr
                            .getPositionSearchItem();

                    mAdapter.mIdMap.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mOfferList.size(); ++i) {
                        mAdapter.mIdMap.put(mOfferList.get(i), i);
                    }

                    mOfferList = (ArrayList<PositionSearchItem>) psr
                            .getPositionSearchItem();

                    mAdapter.clear();
                    mAdapter.addAll(mOfferList);
                    mAdapter.notifydataSetChanged()
                    mList.invalidate();
                    mList.invalidateViews();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(
                    org.holoeverywhere.widget.AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
    }
}
```

EDIT : the getView method from custom adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    this.v = convertView;
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    PositionSearchItem psr = getItem(pos);

    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.result_list_item, parent, false);
    v.setTag(pos);
    // Inject text into view
    ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.result_title_textview))
            .setText(getItem(pos).getTitle());

    // Disable hardware acceleration for the view (it brakes dotted lines on
    // some devices)
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        v.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    // reload list if scrolled to bottom
    int page = 0;
    if (pos > mLastViewed && pos == getCount() - 1) {
        mLastViewed = pos;
        ResultsListFragment frag = new ResultsListFragment_();
        PositionSearchResponse newSearch = frag.processSearch(mTypedText, mSortType, mPage,
                mActivity);
        mPage = mPage + 12;

        if(newSearch != null && newSearch.getPositionSearchItem() != null && newSearch.getPositionSearchItem().size() > 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < newSearch.getPositionSearchItem().size(); ++i) {
                mIdMap.put(newSearch.getPositionSearchItem().get(i), i);
            }
            this.addAll(newSearch.getPositionSearchItem());
        }

    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: use `mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Sorry I just forgot it in my post. I'm using it actually.

Comment: Ok then post the code a bit more , like from where you call this , and when updation happening

Comment: You can update it on Spinner ItemSelected just check my answer i hope it will work for you..

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (update) {

mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this may solve your problem.

Try to set the adatpter again.Place the below code in all the places you wrote the code to update listview

```
mAdapter =  new YourAdapter();
mList.setAdapet(mAdapter)
```

Comment: I tried this also. It has the same behaviour except that it gives a blank list before user interaction.

Comment: did you wrote any animation code in list adapter,just asking since i had the same issue when loading the list with an entry animation..?

Comment: And can you please add the getview function in the post.?

Comment: No I didn't set any animation on it. I've added the getView method.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have created custom list view using adapter and model.

Now each time when you need to update your list view dynamically then you need to clear your previously created list view. Then after you need to fetch all new values and then update same over custom list view.

Hope it helps!